# Doubt about first law of thermodynamics applied to a non-stationary system

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, non-equilibrium, first-law-of-thermodynamics

First law of thermodynamics applied  to a non-stationary system can be given as:

Q+W = del(KE)+del(PE)+del(U)

If no work in done on the system then(W=0)

Q= del(KE)+del(PE)+del(U)

i.e. heat transfer into the system can change the kinetic energy of the system too.If the KE changes then there should be acceleration which means work is done on the system. How is this possible when work is taken to be zero?. Please help.

Comment: "i.e. heat transfer into the system can change the kinetic energy of the system too" this does not logically follow from that equation...

Comment: Hello @lemon, thank you for replying... how is the statement illogical?

Comment: Let me put it like this: suppose $A=B+C$ and $A$ changes. Does it necessarily mean that $B$ also changes?

Comment: In an inelastic collision, the kinetic energy of the colliding bodies (the system) is converted to heat, which is transferred to the surroundings.  No work is done on this system, and its internal energy does not change either (after the bodies equilibrate thermally with the surroundings).

Comment: @lemon That is why I didn't say should change... so if nd when it does change what would be the or are you saying when W=0, del(KE)=0 ?

Comment: @chester miller thank you for taking the time to answer, what happens when the system is not colliding with any other system but there is heat transfer into the system.

Comment: You can always convert heat to work. Then you can convert the work to kinetic energy. So the net effect is heat to kinetic energy. One example is heating an expanding gas to raise a weight. Then allowing the weight to fall to convert its increase in potential energy to kinetic energy.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Ok...so am I right in thinking that when Q amount of heat is transferred to the system(sys1) from another system(sys2) and work done on sys1,W, is taken to be zero, the heat as it passes through the system boundary of sys1 can act as work? i.e. sys2 temperature decreased and so we know the amount of heat but we don't know how this heat will act as it goes through the boundary of sys1. So even though the heat Q does work on the system to increase its KE, we don't have to explicitly give it as work done on the system and so the work done, W, would remain zero........?

Comment: I don't follow what you are saying.  I just gave a simple example of how heat transferred to a system can be converted to kinetic energy within the system in a two step process, involving (first) the use of the heat to increase the potential energy of a weight (part of the system) and then allowing the weight to fall, thus converting the potential energy to kinetic energy.  The net result of both these process steps is the conversion of heat to kinetic energy.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Yup! once the heat has passed the system boundary it can be used to do work inside the system boundary on the system. Since this work won't cross the system boundary it won't show up as work(ie work done 'on the' or 'by the' system)  and keepW= zero, taking it as direct conversion of energy...?

Comment: Well, you can always convert the increased potential energy to kinetic energy within the system just by allowing the weight to fall.